# How to fetch a specific object from JSON using JSONPATH by putting the local variable in query string?

Tags: javascript, jsonpath

I am exploring about [JSONPATH](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath). And I used it in JS to fetch some specific data from the parent JSON.

Let's say the JSON object that I have is,

```
var JSON_OBJECT = {
  "data" : [
      {
          "firstname" : "abn",
          "Lastname" : "Bis"
      },
      {
          "firstname" : "abh",
          "Lastname" : "Bis"
      },
      {
          "firstname" : "pqr",
          "Lastname" : "mno"
      }
  ]
}
```

And I would like to fetch the Objects whose Lastname is "Bis". Then this is my code to fetch those objects.

```
var fire = require('jsonpath')

var s = "$.data[?(@.Lastname == 'Bis')]"

console.log(fire.query(JSON_OBJECT, s))
```

So my question is if I store "Bis" in a variable. Then how to write the same query to get those objects?

This is what I have tried.

```
var dataToBeFound = "Bis"
var s = `$.data[?(@.Lastname == ${dataToBeFound})]`
console.log(fire.query(JSON_OBJECT, s))
```

This gives me an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query will not run properly because of string concatenation. By adding a string variable in Template String you will effectively turn it into a single string and lose the double quotes `" "`. So you'll need to specifically insert the double quotes as part of the value of the string.

See this example to see how your string turns out.

```js
var dataToBeFound = "Bis"
var s = `$.data[?(@.Lastname == ${dataToBeFound})]`

console.log(s)
```

So, you see that you are missing the double quotes in the search expression which breaks the expression. You can tackle this with either string escaping or use a Template Literal `` ` ` `` to insert a value with `" "` around it.

The example below shows you how your value is being output and should work for your JSONPATH query.

```js
var dataToBeFound = `"Bis"`;
var s = `$.data[?(@.Lastname == ${dataToBeFound})]`;

console.log(s)
```

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thank you so much.